# I get URL not found issue error using codeigniter in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have integrated my codeigniter project with Ubuntu 14.04. It was giving me url not found errors after the default controller, which is login controller.

Please find following .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /myapp/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: add the error and the url which you invoked

Comment: "The REquested URL /myapp/admin/validate was not found on this server."

Comment: is there a method called validate() in the admin controller?

Comment: Does your controller filename start with uppercase letter?

Comment: Yes it has a method called  validate() in admin controller

Comment: This system works in 13.10 by the way, just wana know why its not working particulary with 14.04 LTS

Comment: your PHP files, are they lowercase or uppercase ?

Comment: Hey did you found the solution I'm also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 25):

Ok you first need to enable mod_rewrite

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo service apache2 restart
```

then open apache conf file

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

uncomment this line if it is commented

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

you need to change AllowOverride  to **All** - note my root is var/www/html yours might be just var/www

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

Restart apache and that should do the trick

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thank you! I would only add that after doing the last part, i.e. "change AllowOverride to All", you'll need to do the following for the change to take effect: sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Thank you! I just spent 2 hours trying to find this solution.

Comment: It's been 3 years and this advice is still gold to me +1