# Request URL was not found on server codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I started making the project from scratch and I getting a error and I can't figure out what is it that I'm doing wrong.

I made a directory in the controller folder in which I made a new controller and made a route of it in the routes.php but the thing is I'm getting this error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /Codeigniter/item was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Here is my code

**Controller :**

```
  /**
   * Responsible for controlling all the battleplan task logic and management
   *
   * @author gardezi
   */
class Item extends MY_Controller
{


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function index(){
        var_dump("HEllo World");
    }
}
```

and here is the route

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;


$route['item'] = 'item';
```

and the MY_Controller Code is :

```
<?php
  /**
   * This is the controller responsible for redirecting all the logged out user
   * to login page
   *
   * @author gardezi
   */

  class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
      public function __construct() {

          parent::__construct();
      }
  }
```

Comment: try like /Codeigniter/index.php/item if its work, then issue with htaccess.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828542/url-hide-using-codeigniter/38830126#38830126

Comment: @shafiq yeah it worked but it is rerouting me to welcome page it should take me to a blank page and should only show hello world

Comment: What do you have in MY_Controller?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I have added the My controller code to

Comment: Does the Item and MY_Controller controllers residing in the same folder which you have created inside codeigniter's controllers folder?

Comment: Check whether .htaccess is enabled in your project.

Comment: @D555 from where can i see that ??

Comment: @Gardezi You can print phpinfo and then search for "mod_rewrite", if you find it there then you can assume that .htaccess is enabled. If not enabled then you will have to install / enable it, even after that if it does not work then you will have to change configuration in the apache.conf file

Comment: @Gardezi You also mentioned that you created a folder in controller folder, so if the project root folder is codeIgniter, the newly created folder in the controller folder is "abcd" and controller is item then your URL will be something like: http://example.com/abcd/item

Comment: @D555 I have done everything that you said above but still nothing. except for the apache.conf configuration. Can you please guide me thanks

Comment: @Gardezi What was the result of phpinfo()? Where you able to see the mod_rewrite module ? If all above did not work then you will have to make modification in apache.conf file

Answer (score 0):

As you described that you have created the sub-folder inside the controllers folder of Codeigniter directory and have created the controllers here, then you must add the sub-folder name while routing the controller as:

```
$route['item'] = 'subFolderName/item';
```

Comment: I did that but that did not help either it still keeps on throwing the same error

Comment: are you using ubuntu? and does the other codeigniter controllers working fine on your server?

Comment: Yes sheetal I'm using ubuntu and i have another codeigniter project thats working fine

Comment: okay..i've another query, have you gone through the steps mentioned in the following link? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26852680/5331171

Comment: Hello sheetal I did everything that you said but still the error is same